# How to sort by month name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have such query:

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), SUM(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date))
ORDER BY MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date))
```

But results aren't sorted by date. How to sort the by month name: January, February, March etc?

Answer (score 1):

Order the results by the month **number** as opposed to the month **name**, e.g.:

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), Sum(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), Month(Transaction_Date)
ORDER BY Month(Transaction_Date)
```

Comment: Error: Query does not contain the specified expression Month(Transaction_Date) as part of the aggregate function in first case. And Query does not contain the specified expression Transaction_Date as part of the aggregate function in second case.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to include both in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), SUM(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), Month(Transaction_Date)
ORDER BY Month(Transaction_Date);
```

Or just aggregate by `MONTH()`:

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), SUM(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Month(Transaction_Date)
ORDER BY Month(Transaction_Date);
```

The `MONTHNAME()` is then applied after the aggregations.

Alternatively, if the `Transaction_Date`s are all from the same year, use aggregation functions:

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), SUM(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date))
ORDER BY MIN(Transaction_Date);
```

Note that you may also want to be including the year along with the month -- that is a best practice, because usually you don't want to mix data from different years in the same month.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering by the month name would be alphabetical but if you just order by Month(transaction_date) ASC/DESC that should order your results correctly.

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), SUM(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Month(Transaction_Date)
ORDER BY Month(Transaction_Date)
```

Comment: If you could provide an example would make your answer a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)), SUM(Sales)
FROM Sales
GROUP BY MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date))
ORDER BY Transaction_Date ASC
```

Note that :

ASC - for ascending A to Z order

DESC - for descending Z to A order

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should order by transaction date.

```
   SELECT 
 MonthName(Month(Transaction_Date)) 
    As Month_Name , SUM(Sales)
    FROM Sales
   GROUP BY Month_Name
  ORDER BY Transaction_Date
```